# DataTables custom search filter is not filtering table in a column that contains HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatable, datatables

I have a datatable that contains a link to show more details about an item.

I created a select drop down that contains just the unique values in that column for quick filtering to just that specific item.

However, when selecting that item, the table is filtered, but no rows are displayed. If I remove the extra HTML in the column, then the drop down works fine.

The select element's options have the correct values and there doesn't appear to be anything out of the ordinary and there are no console error logs. It just doesn't filter with the extra HTML link.

I `console.log(val)` in the `onChange` event and it's just the string that is passed `column.search()`.

If I use the DataTable's own built-in search box, the column is filtered correctly even with the extra HTML link. It is only when I use the select drop down that it doesn't filter (if it has the HTML link).

**Does anyone see what I could be doing wrong?**

**My Template**

```
<table id="MyDataTable" data-page-length="25" data-order='[[ 0, "asc"]]' class=" data-tables">
//..
    <td data-sort="{{$user->role_name}}">
        {{$user->role_name}}
        <a href="somelink.html?id={{$user->role_id}}">Details</a>
    </td>
</table>
```

**A rendered portion**

```
<td data-sort="Admin">Admin <a href="somelink.html?id=5">Details</a></td>
```

**The javascript generates this:**

```
<select id="select_role" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Show All</option>
  <option value="Regular User">Regular User</option>
  <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
  <option value="Super Admin">Super Admin</option>
  <option value="Enterprise">Enterprise</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
let dtable = $("#MyDataTable").DataTable();
let dropdown = $("#select_role");
let column = dtable.column(3); // The index of the column that has the data

dropdown.append('<option value="">Show All</option>');

// Get the unique values in the column and strip HTML
column.data().unique().each(function (d, j) {
    //Strip any extra HTML that comes with that field, like styling.
    let content = d.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
    dropdown.append('<option value="' + content + '">' + content + '</option>');
});

dropdown.on('change', function () {
    let val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
    console.log(val);
    column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
});
```

Comment: I have a lot of datatables with cells with html on my projects and it always worked well.. Did you tried to filter like this: table.column(3).search('value').draw() ?